# Calling a function on element of struct which is a nil pointer

Tags: go, struct

In Go, however, the function to be called by the `Expression.Name()` syntax is entirely determined by the type of Expression and not by the particular run-time value of that expression, including nil - [copied](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/wcrZ3P1zeAk/WI88iQgFMvwJ)

So we can call a `method` using a struct instance which is nil.

Consider the following program:

```
 package main

    import "fmt"

    type T struct {
        V int
        tt *T
    }

    func (t *T) hello() string {
       return "world"
   } 

    func main() {
        var t *T = nil
        fmt.Println(t, t.hello()) // <nil> world
        fmt.Println(t, t.tt.hello()) // panic
    }
```

Why `fmt.Println(t, t.hello())` worked?

**But**

`fmt.Println(t, t.tt.hello())` panicked?.

My understanding is that both `t` and `t.tt` are `nil` pointers. So `t.tt.hello()` should not panic as Calling a method on a nil struct pointer is allowed in golang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding is that both t and t.tt are nil pointers. So
>   t.tt.hello() should not panic as Calling a method on a nil struct
>   pointer is allowed in golang.

Your "understanding" is wrong.`t.tt` should and does `panic`.

---

> [Go 1.2 Release Notes (December 2013)](https://golang.org/doc/go1.2)
>
> [Use of nil](https://golang.org/doc/go1.2#use_of_nil)
>
> The language now specifies that, for safety reasons, certain uses of
>   nil pointers are guaranteed to trigger a run-time panic. For instance,
>   in Go 1.0, given code like
>
> ```
> type T struct {
>     X [1<<24]byte
>     Field int32
> }
>
> func main() {
>     var x *T
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> the nil pointer x could be used to access memory incorrectly: the
>   expression x.Field could access memory at address 1<<24. To prevent
>   such unsafe behavior, in Go 1.2 the compilers now guarantee that any
>   indirection through a nil pointer, such as illustrated here but also
>   in nil pointers to arrays, nil interface values, nil slices, and so
>   on, will either panic or return a correct, safe non-nil value. In
>   short, any expression that explicitly or implicitly requires
>   evaluation of a nil address is an error. The implementation may inject
>   extra tests into the compiled program to enforce this behavior.
>
> Further details are in the [design document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/14DgGJKGQeBTNJDXo3YxnlSwv7ouRqvj7BMmZw17vWV0/pub).

---

> In short, any expression that explicitly or implicitly requires
>   evaluation of a nil address is an error.

Therefore, the following behavior is expected. The indirection for `t.tt` through a `nil` value of `t` fails with a `panic`.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type T struct {
    V  int
    tt *T
}

func (t *T) hello() string {
    return "world"
}

type A struct {
    a int
}

func main() {
    var t *T = nil
    fmt.Println(t)            // nil
    fmt.Println(t.tt.hello()) // panic
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Szwx5MqNHkQ

Output:

```
<nil>
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox136049644/main.go:21 +0x84
```

Answer (score 4):

Precisely speaking, `t` is a nil pointer, and `t.tt` doesn't exist at all.  The panic you see is the result of dereferencing `t`, not `t.tt`. This is just obscured by the fact that `t.tt` is (or would be, if `t` were initialized) also a pointer.

This can be made more clear by accessing the `V` field of `t`:

```
func (t *T) foo() {
    fmt.Println(t.V) // Will panic, if `t` is nil
}
```

The reason the first test doesn't panic is that calling a method on `t` doesn't actually dereference `t`. Calling `t.Hello()` is roughly the equivalent of calling `Hello(t)`, so won't panic unless/until `t` is actually dereferenced within the function.

Answer (score 2):

`t` is nil,there is no `t.tt`.

And `t.hello()` is like `hello(t)`, `hello(nil)` don't panic, but `t.tt` do.

[Remember: a method is just a function with a receiver argument.](https://tour.golang.org/methods/2)

[Method expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions)

Answer (score -1):

`nil` is the zero value for pointers

```
// nil is a predeclared identifier representing the zero value for a
// pointer, channel, func, interface, map, or slice type.
var nil Type // Type must be a pointer, channel, func, interface, map, or slice type
```

Source: https://golang.org/src/builtin/builtin.go?h=nil#L101

To understand `nil` this video is fantastic
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ynoY2xz-F8s